# Create dataframe from large data set with out load it on driver before

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

With not enough driver's memory, I need to convert large data set to dataframe.
That data is received from HTTP request/response.

Short handed example,

```
// Size of this is over GBs
var dataFromHttp = http('http://my.com/verylargedata')

// Convert data to custom Scala/Java Object Array
var objectSeq = convertDataToSeq(dataFromHttp)

// Convert it to dataframe
var df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(objectSeq, ...)
```

Is there any way to make `df` directly on executor?
(`dataFromHttp` should not be loaded on driver)

Comment: just an idea : start with a empty dataframe, use `mapPartitions` to populate it with data

Answer (score 0):

A starting point would be to read the data with one executor, flatten the result and transform the resulting RDD to a dataframe. Generally, executors have much more memory than the driver so it might work for you.

```scala
// we start with a one row RDD, and flatten it.
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(1)).flatMap( _ => {
    val dataFromHttp = http("http://my.com/verylargedata")
    convertDataToSeq(dataFromHttp)
})

// we convert it to a dataframe
val columnNames = Seq("A", "B", ...)
val df = rdd.toDF(columnNames :_*)
```